# How can this problem be solved, backtracking? Vectors?

Tags: c++

Hi guys I'm new to programming and I have this problem and I don't kinda know how to do it:

I've thought that maybe I can use list, vectors or backtracking but those are just ideas. I don't know how to implement those.

> The Data Structures teacher wants to distribute projects to students, for them to participate at FILS Scientific Session. She prepared k projects and she has n students who want to participate (n>=k). Each project must be given at least once, but the n students can work in teams to implement a certain project. This means that each project is given to a team of students, which is built from 1 or more students. The values n and k will be read from the console, as well as the title of the subject and the name of the students.
>
> You will have to:
>   Display at the console all possibilities of distributing the k projects to the n students, as well the number of possible solution, in the below form:
>
> For n = 3 (students), k = 2 (projects)
>   There are 6 solutions:
>
> ```
> Tom - "Java Animation " , Jane - "Java Animation" , Kate - "3D Game"
> Tom - "Java Animation " , Jane - "3D Game" , Kate - "Java Animation"
> Tom - "Java Animation " , Jane - "3D Game" , Kate - "3D Game"
> Tom - "3D Game " , Jane - "Java Animation" , Kate - "Java Animation"
> Tom - "3D Game " , Jane - "Java Animation" , Kate - "3D Game"
> Tom - "3D Game " , Jane - "3D Game" , Kate - "Java Animation"
> ```

Can someone help? The programing language is C++. I was thinking of using backtracing but I don't have a concrete idea how to use that.

Comment: Please read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): _"3. Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."_

Comment: have a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest you start with implementing is a function which goes through all of the possible assignments of a single project to a group of students; then do the same thing, but when some of the students are unavailable; then you can use backtracking and recursion to assign the first project, then the second project given the assignment of the first etc.

Hope this helps.